The webpage does not show the database values even after including thymeleaf for front-end
I am creating a basic banking app REST api using Spring 3 and thymeleaf for front-end. The program was working when i used postman to manipulate the data present in my local database. But, when i try to create a front end webpage using thymeleaf dependency for doing the same thing, the data present in the db does not reflect on the index page. The account is being created and sent to the database but the data is not being visualized in the index.html. What should i do?
This is my controller class:
import com.bankapp.banking.dto.AccountDto;
import com.bankapp.banking.service.AccountService;
import com.bankapp.banking.service.impl.InsufficientFundsException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.List;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/accounts")

public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    public AccountController(AccountService accountService) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    // Add Account Page
    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String addAccountForm(Model model) {
        AccountDto accountDto = new AccountDto();
        model.addAttribute("accountDto", accountDto);
        return "add-account";
    }

    // Add Account Form Submission
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addAccount(@ModelAttribute AccountDto accountDto) {
        accountService.createAccount(accountDto);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    //modified after gemini
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView getAllAccounts() {
        List<AccountDto> accounts = accountService.getAllAccounts();

        // Print the size of the accounts list for debugging
        System.out.println("Number of accounts retrieved: " + accounts.size());

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        modelAndView.addObject("accounts", accounts);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String getAccountById(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        AccountDto accountDto = accountService.getAccountById(id);
        model.addAttribute("accountDto", accountDto);
        return "account-details";
    }

    // Deposit Page
    @GetMapping("/{id}/deposit")
    public String depositForm(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        AccountDto accountDto = accountService.getAccountById(id);
        model.addAttribute("accountDto", accountDto);
        return "deposit";
    }

    //modified after gemini
    @PostMapping("/{id}/deposit")
    public String deposit(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam("amount") Double amount) {
        try {
            accountService.deposit(id, amount);
            return "redirect:/accounts/" + id;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Handle invalid deposit amount error (e.g., display error message in view)
            return "redirect:/accounts/" + id + "?error=" + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    // Withdraw Page
    @GetMapping("/{id}/withdraw")
    public String withdrawForm(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        AccountDto accountDto = accountService.getAccountById(id);
        model.addAttribute("accountDto", accountDto);
        return "withdraw";
    }

    @PostMapping("/{id}/withdraw")
    public String withdraw(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam("amount") Double amount) {
        try {
            accountService.withdraw(id, amount);
            return "redirect:/accounts/" + id;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | InsufficientFundsException e) {
            // Handle invalid withdrawal amount or insufficient funds error
            return "redirect:/accounts/" + id + "?error=" + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    //modified after gemini v
    @PostMapping("/{id}/delete")
    public String deleteAccount(@PathVariable Long id) {
        accountService.deleteAccount(id);
        // Redirect to confirmation page after deletion (optional)
        // return "redirect:/accounts";
        return "redirect:/accounts/" + id + "/confirm-delete";  // Redirect to confirmation page first
    }

    //modified after gemini v
    @PostMapping("/{id}/confirmDelete")
    public String confirmDelete(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        AccountDto accountDto = accountService.getAccountById(id);
        model.addAttribute("accountDto", accountDto);
        return "confirm-delete";
    }
}

This is my index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Banking App - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container my-2">

    <h1>Accounts</h1>
    <a th:href="@{/accounts/add}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Create New Account</a>
    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Account Holder Name</th>
            <th>Balance</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="accountDto : ${accounts}">
            <td th:text="${accountDto.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${accountDto.accountHolderName}"></td>
            <td th:text="${accountDto.balance}"></td>
            <td>
                <!-- Deposit Button -->
                <a th:href="@{'/accounts/' + ${accountDto.id} + '/deposit'}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Deposit</a>
                <!-- Withdraw Button -->
                <a th:href="@{'/accounts/' + ${accountDto.id} + '/withdraw'}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Withdraw</a>
                <!-- Delete Button -->
                <form th:action="@{'/accounts/' + ${accountDto.id} + '/delete'}" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <th:block th:if="${param.error}">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <span th:text="${param.error}"></span>
        </div>
    </th:block>
</div>

</body>
</html>

This is what it shows once i open my localhost:8080 page:
enter image description here
I need some help to resolve this.

Is there any exception printed in the console ?

Not to my knowledge
